# How to know the logic of multilevel menu event bubbling

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

I'm trying to understand the logic happening in my basic multilevel menu click event. I understood what happening on clicking on "About" menu in the navigation. And it works as per my expecation of code. But when i click on "Profile" menu (Submenu of "About" menu), JS makes it's sublevel menu "display:none". I tried to think in the aspect of even bubbling. But eventhough the bubbling happens here, it should not be working like this. Actually for me, its really complicated to understand how JS works here. It would be a Great Help if anyone can explain with a simple and understandable way. Thank You Very Much in Advance!!!

```js
let menus = document.querySelectorAll(".main-navigation ul li a");
    menus.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.parentElement.querySelector("ul")) {
            item.parentElement.classList.add("has-submenu");
        }
    });

    let submenu = document.querySelectorAll(".has-submenu");
    submenu.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            let ul = e.target.parentElement.querySelector("ul");
            let cs = window.getComputedStyle(ul).display;
            
            if (cs === "none") {
                ul.style.cssText = "display:block";
            }
            else {
                ul.style.cssText = "display:none";
            }


        });
    });
```

```css
.main-navigation ul {list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;font-family:arial;}
    .main-navigation ul li {padding:.35rem;background:#f9f9f9;}
    .main-navigation ul li ul {padding-left:1rem;display:none;}
    .main-navigation ul li a {display:block;text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<div class="main-navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About +</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Profile +</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="">History</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Management</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Vision</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Mission</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Services +</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Web Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Web Development</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

If you add a `console.log` inside your `click` handler you will notice that the event for the nested item is called **twice**.

You probably knew that it could happen and you used `preventDefault`.

However, `preventDefault` is for the browser's default effects (for example, it prevents your page to refresh as you put an `href` attribute) but in your case the double behaviour is from your own custom listener.

This means, you need to add [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) that *prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases*.

### Working Demo

```js
let menus = document.querySelectorAll(".main-navigation ul li a");
menus.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.parentElement.querySelector("ul")) {
    item.parentElement.classList.add("has-submenu");
  }
});

let submenu = document.querySelectorAll(".has-submenu");
submenu.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    let ul = e.target.parentElement.querySelector("ul");
    let cs = window.getComputedStyle(ul).display;

    if (cs === "none") {
      ul.style.cssText = "display:block";
    } else {
      ul.style.cssText = "display:none";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.main-navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

.main-navigation ul li {
  padding: .35rem;
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

.main-navigation ul li ul {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  display: none;
}

.main-navigation ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About +</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Profile +</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Management</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Vision</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Mission</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Services +</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Web Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Web Development</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I'll mark your solution as Right Answer. But before that let me ask you few doubts. When i use `let submenu = document.querySelectorAll(".has-submenu a");  instead of (".has-submenu") everything works perfectly without declaring even "stopPropogation". Can you explain that what is happening there.

Comment: The current implementation adds the listener do 3 `ul` elements and you have the "bug" because everything else is inside the `ul`. If you add `a` in the `querySelector` you will target 9 `a` elements and it works without stopPropagation because you're clicking only on the `a`. However, you're adding the listener to *all* `a` elements inside `.has-submenu` which is not the desired behaviour I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Can you do the following steps and let me know feedback:
`1. Click on "Profile" menu
2. Now you able to see that submenu of "Profile" is gets "display:none"
3. It should be "display:block" as per i already made it "display:none" with CSS`